# How do i simplify and quicken 3 queries with each based off the next?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

A few years ago i made a simple t-card system for work and its been working as intended since (handling about 300 jobs), now its nowhere near perfect and as such with the workload ramping up over the last few months due to the pandemic (handling about 2000 jobs) its slowing down massively going from 30 second load time (not great anyway) to sometimes 10 minutes or just timing out.

So the way its currently set up is i get all the jobs dates with:

```
                            $getdates = $conn->prepare("SELECT delivery_date FROM orders INNER JOIN stages ON orders.id = stages.order_id WHERE isnull(stages.stage_8_name)  GROUP BY delivery_date");
                            $getdates->execute();

                            if($getdates->rowCount()) {

                                foreach ($getdates->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {                                          

                                    $delivery_date = $row['delivery_date'];
                                    
                                    $getdates_c = $conn->prepare("SELECT delivery_date FROM orders INNER JOIN stages ON orders.id = stages.order_id WHERE isnull(stages.stage_8_name) AND delivery_date = :delivery_date  ");
                                    $getdates_c->execute(array(':delivery_date' => $delivery_date));


                                    $number_of_cards = $getdates_c->rowCount();
```

This gets a date for all the jobs that have yet to be completed. I then make a table header with each date and the count of jobs for that date. Next I check what Drivers are unavailable that day with:

```
$getstaff = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE position = 4 ORDER BY name asc");
                        $getstaff->execute();
                            foreach ($getstaff->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) { 
                                $staff_id = $row['id']; 

                            $gethol = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff_holiday WHERE staff_id = :staff_id AND day = :holday AND (type = 'Holiday' OR type = 'Holiday Half')");
                            $gethol->execute(array(':staff_id' => $staff_id, ':holday' => $delivery_date));

                                foreach ($gethol->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) { 
                                    $type_hol = $row['type']; 
                                    $staff_id = $row['staff_id'];
```

And add that into the table header.

I then basically repeat the date query for the body of the table with:

```
$getdates = $conn->prepare("SELECT delivery_date FROM orders INNER JOIN stages ON orders.id = stages.order_id WHERE isnull(stages.stage_8_name)  GROUP BY delivery_date");
                                $getdates->execute();

                                if($getdates->rowCount()) {

                                    foreach ($getdates->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {   
                                        $delivery_date = $row['delivery_date'];
```

and then using that date cycle through an array of vans and get the number of jobs per van and do a sub table header with van number and amount of jobs:

```
$vans = array(0,1,2,3,4,5);

                                            foreach ($vans as $this_van) {

                                                $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `orders` INNER JOIN stages ON orders.id = stages.order_id WHERE isnull(stages.stage_8_name) AND orders.delivery_date = :delivery_date AND orders.van = :this_van "; 
                                                $result = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                                                $result->execute(array(':delivery_date' => $delivery_date,':this_van' => $this_van )); 
                                                $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

then finally I get all the jobs for each van on that specific day and list them in order of job:

```
$getproduction = $conn->prepare("SELECT orders.about 20 different fields, stages.another 20 fields FROM orders INNER JOIN stages ON orders.id = stages.order_id WHERE isnull(stages.stage_8_name) AND orders.delivery_date = :delivery_date AND orders.van = :this_van  ORDER BY drop_no ASC");
                                                $getproduction->bindParam(':delivery_date', $delivery_date);
                                                $getproduction->bindParam(':this_van', $this_van);
                                                $getproduction->execute();
                                                    foreach ($getproduction->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {  
                                                        $order_id = $row['id'];
```

so this lists every bit of information about that job.

All in all i end up with a list of dates with van numbers below and jobs listed below van numbers.[image: Tcards sample]

Any help in simplifying this or just getting it running quicker would be amazing. Thanks.

EDIT: OK based on your comments I've slimmed everything down to test and so far got this:

```
// Gets all orders and sorts by drop number
    $getorders = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id INNER JOIN addresses on orders.address_id = addresses.address_id ORDER BY drop_no");
    $getorders->execute();

    $result = $getorders->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// groups order by date, van, drop
    foreach ( $result as $value ) {
        $group[$value['delivery_date']][$value['van_no']][$value['drop_no']][] = $value;
    }

// outputs orders by date -> van -> drop

    var_dump($group);
```

like so:

```
array (size=2)
  '2020-08-25' => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=8)
              'orders_id' => string '6' (length=1)
              'customer_id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'address_id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'van_no' => string '1' (length=1)
              'drop_no' => string '0' (length=1)
              'delivery_date' => string '2020-08-25' (length=10)
              'customer_name' => string 'One' (length=3)
              'address_postcode' => string 'b1' (length=2)
          1 => 
            array (size=8)
              'orders_id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'customer_id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'address_id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'van_no' => string '1' (length=1)
              'drop_no' => string '1' (length=1)
              'delivery_date' => string '2020-08-25' (length=10)
              'customer_name' => string 'One' (length=3)
              'address_postcode' => string 'b1' (length=2)
```

Any help in how i would print a header of delivery_date then sub header of van_no with all jobs printed below their van_no in drop_no order? everything i use to echo it out repeats the date and van for each job.

Thanks again.

Comment: 1) the 2nd query in the 1st code snippet seems pointless. You already have that information from the 1st query. 2) if you have a foreach loop based on a query result in which you issue another query, then you basically implemented a database join in php. Do the join in the database. 3) repeating the same query again and again is waste of time and resources. Just store the results in an array to reuse the values without repeating the query.

Comment: Yes. See about JOINs (again), and note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate.

Comment: @Strawberry the OP uses group by instead of distinct, so that oart is fine. Although adding a count(*)  may help in case of the first code snippet.

Comment: @Shadow That part is not fine!